# Is there a way to allow user to select text from many `EditText`s in a row (which are in ListView)?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textselection

I'm trying to use a ListView for a message history in an IM app, which previously used single WebView for displaying history, and I'm thinking about how to implement text selection.

I see at least one major problem — the `ListView` recycles views, so the naive way wouldn't work, if user tries to select text from a lot of items, and scrolls the list far away from the beginning of the selection. But anyway, Android doesn't let selection to "jump" from one `EditText` to another. So, is there a (cool) way to implement such feature? (It's OK if it will work on Android 4.0+ only.)

My current example is made of the following code:

Adapter:

```
private class MessagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public EditText getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final EditText result = (EditText)(convertView == null ?
                LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_row, parent, false) :
                convertView);

        result.setText(getItem(position));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:cursorVisible="false"
          android:editable="false"
          android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

I can select text in a single `EditText`, but not in many `EditText`s at once.

Comment: u want to select part of text in edittext or full text in edittext?

Comment: @adcom Yes, I want to make a partial selection. (the first and last EditTexts can have a part of text selected)

Comment: @SargeBorsch can your adapter class and what are you trying to do.

Comment: as a workaround you could add edittext programmatically inside a scrollview. This way your edittext will not be recycled.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin in short, I'm trying to use a ListView for a message history in an IM app, which previously used single WebView for displaying history, and I'm thinking about how to implement text selection.

Comment: @IllegalArgument this defeats the purpose of using ListView over WebView (the item counts will be huge)

Comment: @SargeBorsch tried in adapter to use textWatcher?

Comment: @SargeBorsch please post the adapter code

Comment: @adcom not yet. You mean, using it to counter the view recycling (detect changing text)?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin there's nothing interesting really, I'm using "stock" ArrayAdapter for now while testing with just one ('getView') method overridden to use EditTexts for displaying items.

Comment: @SargeBorsch http://pastie.org/pastes/9449320/text

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I added some code, including the adapter.

Comment: Any luck ? @SargeBorsch

Comment: @adcom nope, I don't know how to allow the selection to span many EditTexts, even without any scrolling

Comment: @SadeepDarshana Nope